# Is there any guide to submit catalyst app?

Tags: swift, macos, xcode11

We have created new app which support iphone, ipad and mac catalyst from xcode 11. We have also create apple distribution profile to upload binary. But at submission time apple says that beta binaries are not supported. I have used xcode 11 and if i will de select mac then i can submit build.

In developer apple i havent seen any guide on uploading mac catalyst apps. Anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: There seems to be a distinct lack of information about Mac Catalyst when it comes to submitting your binary.  I get a different message, "Profile is not a 'Mac Catalyst App Store' profile." and I have tried both App Store and Mac App Store types.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Still not solved. Not able to find any proper documentation for this

Answer (score 16):

In order to upload apps converted with Catalyst to App Store,

<del>you'll need to create a new Mac OS app entry in App Store Connect.
Simply click on the 'Plus' icon in AppStoreConnect, click on new MacOS
app.</del>

In the existing App Store app page, click on the plus icon "VERSION OR PLATFORM", and select Mac OS.

Your Mac Catalyst app shares **the same bundle ID** as your iOS app. In your Xcode organizer, one of them shows in the iOS section and one in the macOS app section. Uploads from Xcode should automatically go into the same app record on App Store Connect.

You can then finish the details (Mac app screenshots, descriptions, etc.) in the app page and submit it for review.

There will be one apps displayed in your AppStoreConnect and 2 platforms in it, one for the iOS and one for the macOS.

Comment: hey, so i followed the steps. however, when i go to submit it i do not see the bundle ID to allow me to submit to the appstore....does that make sense lol..

Comment: Hi @jbiser361 I think in the most recent version of the App Store Connect the Mac Catalyst app will share the same bundle ID as the iOS app. And in the store page, you only need to select one bundle ID for your iOS app in the Basic Information. And you can create the Mac entry in the store page without providing a seperate bundle ID. In Xcode, uploading seems to be fine for Mac Catalyst app as well. (Point out if something is not correct here) ;)

Comment: @jbiser361 I have updated the answer content regarding this.